# Fetch walking distance on HealthKit by splits

Tags: swift, healthkit, pace

I am working on an app that uses `HealthKit` framework to pull data and display it to the user. I have been able to check how many meters has the user walked in a given `HKWorkoutSession`, by creating a `HKStatisticsQuery`.

Now, I want to get more details about this data. Basically, I want to divide the total distance walked in splits of 1 km, and display how much time each of these splits took. I haven't found any solutions online to achieve this.